# how to add custom functionality on click of Done button in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to add a custom functionality of mine, while we click the "Done" button displayed on top of the screen when the `MPMoviePlayerController` goes to full screen mode.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register for the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification. This notification's userInfo property has an object for `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey`, check that and see if it is `MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited`. If that's the case, your user has hit done and you can go ahead with your custom functionality. If you want to stop it from ending playback altogether, things might get more complicated.

You can also register for the `MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification` notification or check the `MPMoviePlayerController` fullscreen property.

Comment: It's a year old answer I know, but this does not work for me. `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` only fires when the movie comes to it's endpoint and never when the button is tapped.

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerWillEnterExitFullScreenNotification` works, but it also captures the <- -> arrow button on the right side of the bottom control, which I don't want to do.

Comment: @DBD You'll get a different notification when the stop/pause button is tapped, MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification.

Comment: The first part works for me. I was adding MPMoviePlayerViewController view as a sub view of my viewController view. And Done button was not working. It was just pausing music. Now I have control, I am able to dismiss. Thanks :)